# Matlab imread return 4 channel matrix

Tags: image, matlab, gimp

I do imread image in Matlab, and it returns a 4-channel image:

im: 1012x972x4 uint8.

Which format is this image? How to check its color format(RGB, CMYK, etc)? I opened it in Gimp and the color profile is simply sRGB built-in

Comment: What does `imfinfo` return?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you are asking. A [color profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile) is something completely different from the "format" of an image file and the number of channels. As far as I know, the `infinfo` function will not return any real Information about the ICC profile other that it's name. For TIFF files, you can use [`iccread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/iccread.html) to read embedded profile data.

Comment: My wild guess in the image is sRGB in Gimp is that you are dealing with an RGBA image (alpha channel)

Comment: From the documentation, the only time `imread` will return a 4 channel image is if the image was CMYK and is TIFF.  You should really read the docs for more details: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html

Comment: @rayryeng: the documentation does not say *only*. Indeed it also mentions 4-channel RAS images and, from experience, TIFFs with an alpha channel also result in four channels.

Comment: At least in R2014, it looks like running `imfinfo` on your image will return a structure with a `ColorType` property. That should tell you what Matlab thinks is going on. http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imfinfo.html

Comment: For PNG, alpha information is returned through an extra output argument, not through a fourth channel. @Dzung Nguyen: What is the file format of your image file?

Comment: @horchler, as far as I understand, if Gimp says the "color profile" is "sRGB built-in" this means there is no explicit associated ICC color profile – but isn't it fair to assume that the color format is RGB?

Answer (score 0):

From `imread()` [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html):

> The return value A is an array containing the image data. If the file
>   contains a grayscale image, A is an M-by-N array. If the file contains
>   a truecolor image, A is an M-by-N-by-3 array. **For TIFF files
>   containing color images that use the CMYK color space, A is an
>   M-by-N-by-4 array.** See TIFF in the Format-Specific Information section
>   for more information.

So the answer is apparently that this image's color space is CMYK.

If you want to check for a general input, then, from the same page:

> To determine which color space is used, use `imfinfo` to get information
>   about the graphics file and look at the value of the
>   PhotometricInterpretation field.